# Can we differentiate between frame and non-frame loads with Ci in firefox addon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, firefox-addon

In chrome extension, while listening to response headers we can differentiate between frame and non-frame loads e.g.

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
      if(details.type!="main_frame")  // will always return main_frame due to filter       
      {
        return;
      }

      // do something
      return {responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders};
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"],types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]}, ['responseHeaders','blocking']);
```

In comparison to this in firefox, can we do the same:

```
httpResponseObserver =  
{  
  observe: function(subject, topic, data)  
  {  

    if (topic == "http-on-examine-response") 
    {
        var channel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel); 

        if(channel.something!="main_frame)
           return;
    }
  },
...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure about Ci but you can easily do it with load flags:

https://github.com/Noitidart/loadcontext-and-http-modify-observer/blob/master/bootstrap.js

test for the `LOAD_INITIAL_DOCUMENT_URI` so like:

```
if (oHttp.loadFlags & oHttp.LOAD_INITIAL_DOCUMENT_URI) {
```

frames will only have `LOAD_DOCUMENT_URI`. (non frame windows also have this but they dont have the initial one)

note: if you have redirects all redirects have LOAD_INITIAL_DOCUMENT_URI so you have to catch the last one, or just use `http-on-response` instead of the `http-modify-response` (i prbobably didnt type these observers right)

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. It also filters out images, js and other stuff